# Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/myimg.jpg'. (storage/unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm using firebase within my vue project. I have a section where I can upload images to firebase storage. I setup a method that allowed me to upload an image which worked great but once I set the rules on firebase to

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Allow read access to everyone.
    allow read: if true;
    
    // Allow write access only if the user is authenticated.
    allow write: if auth != null;
  }
}
```

now no matter what I do I am getting a permission error on my method.

*Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/myimg.jpg'. (storage/unauthorized)*

even if i go try to change the rules to `allow write: if true` Im still getting the error

here is my function below.

```
async UpdateImage(){
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  if (user) {
    try {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/img1.jpg`);
      console.log('User Authenticated:', auth.currentUser);

      const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, this.$refs.ImageItem.files[0])
      console.log('Image Upload' + snapshot)
    
      const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);    
      console.log(downloadURL)
    )
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
  } else {
    alert("user is not authenticated")
  }
}
```

The `console.log('User Authenticated:', auth.currentUser)`
shows that when testing that I am logged in. I get the UserImpl object but

I've tweaked the method so much now trying to figure it out that it's probably a mess, but no matter what I do I cant seam to upload images as an authorized user.

Comment: I modified the rules a little bit and It appears to be working for me now. I would still love to get others opinions on it just to see if there is a better way of doing this. 

`rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
    
    allow write: if request.auth != null;
    
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a matching `allow` declaration for the folder you are writing to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{imageId} {    
      // Allow read access to everyone.
      allow read: if true;

      // Allow write access only if the user is authenticated.
      allow write: if auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```